# I receive the following error while trying to get the index of a class that inherits from CollectionBase: Cannot apply indexing with []

Tags: c#, collectionbase

I have a class that inherits from `CollectionBase`.

```
public NavigationMenuItemsCollection MenuItems { get; set; }
```

I have a method that is attempting to get the item from the index, but it's not working.

```
public void ActivatePage(int index)
{
   NavigationMenuItem navigationMenuItem = (NavigationMenuItem)MenuItems[0];
}
```

[image]

CollectionBase inherits from `IList`, `ICollection`, and `IEnumerable`. So I thought it could be indexed. Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CollectionBase` implements `IList`'s indexer property with an explicit interface implementation, meaning that you'd normally have to cast the collection as an `IList` in order to have access to it.

```
NavigationMenuItem navigationMenuItem = (NavigationMenuItem)((IList)MenuItems)[0];
```

If you are able to modify the source code of `NavigationMenuItemsCollection`, you should be able to add an indexer to it yourself, as shown in the first example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348304(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public class NavigationMenuItemCollection : CollectionBase  {

   public NavigationMenuItem this[ int index ]  {
      get  {
         return( (NavigationMenuItem) List[index] );
      }
      set  {
         List[index] = value;
      }
   }
   ...
```

Comment: Ah. That makes a lot of sense. I added the indexer and it worked perfectly. Thanks!